# MVVM-Light EventToCommand Behavior for CheckBox Checked/Unchecked in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight-4.0, mvvm-light

I would like to handle the Checked and Unchecked events of a Checkbox control and execute a command in my ViewModel. I wired up an EventTrigger for both the Checked and Unchecked events as follows:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="chkIsExtendedHr" IsChecked="{Binding Schedule.Is24Hour, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
            <GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command:EventToCommand 
                CommandParameter="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=chkIsExtendedHr}"
                Command="{Binding Path=SetCloseTime, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Unchecked">
            <GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command:EventToCommand 
                CommandParameter="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=chkIsExtendedHr}"
                Command="{Binding Path=SetCloseTime, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</CheckBox>
```

I defined a RelayCommand in my ViewModel and wired up an action for it:

```
public RelayCommand<Boolean> SetCloseTime{ get; private set; }

   ...

SetCloseTime= new RelayCommand<bool>(ExecuteSetCloseTime);
```

The parameter in the action for the command always resolves to the previous state of the CheckBox, e.g. false when the CheckBox is checked, and true when the CheckBox is unchecked.

```
void ExecuteSetCloseTime(bool isChecked) 
{
    if (isChecked)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Is this expected behavior?

I have a workaround where I have separate triggers (and commands) for the Checked and Unchecked and use a `RelayCommand` instead of `RelayCommand<bool>`.  Each command executes correctly when the CheckBox is checked and unchecked. Feels a little dirty though - even dirtier than having UI code in my ViewModel :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you handle your actions in your Schedule.Is24Hour. In setter you always can see when that property is changed.

Comment: Damir, that's a good suggestion. For some reason I never thought to do work in the changed notification that's fired after the setter.

Comment: George, in my opinion it's not best way to create two commands to see if some checkbox is checked. What you can also do is to create some class that in constructor subscribe to your ViewModel property changed. Then look if property name is Is24Hour and if it is do work on your viewmodel. That class should take your ViewModel in constructor and you create it in ViewModel contructor like new SomeIs24HourService(this). And in that way you can manipulate your viewmodel and you decoupled that funcionality.

Answer (score 4):

I think using "Click" event instead of "Checked" or "UnChecked" can solve this problem with just one command and no additional code.
In XAML it will look like,

```
<i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
<GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command:EventToCommand CommandParameter="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=chkIsExtendedHr}" Command="{Binding Path=SetCloseTime, Mode=OneWay}" />
</i:EventTrigger>
```

now rest of you code should work the you wanted,

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

i do this for checking checkbox

for view

```
 <CheckBox Margin="126,0,0,0"  IsChecked="{Binding UseNOCODE, Mode=TwoWay}" Content="Reply Messages ?" />
```

for the modelview

```
 private bool _useNOCODE = false;
    public bool UseNOCODE
    {
        get
        {
            return _useNOCODE;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_useNOCODE == value)
            {
                return;
            }
            _useNOCODE = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("UseNOCODE");
            UseNoCodeChecked();
        }
    }
 private void UseNoCodeChecked()
    {//check the properties and what you like}
```