# Calling a command in my ViewModel from a binding to an event in my XAML?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, mvvm, mvvm-light

I am currently writing a Windows 8 application. I am trying to call a method in my ViewModel. I want this method to be called when an item is double clicked. I have defined the following DataTemplate in my XAML to do this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Width="185" Height="185" Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding Path=Image}" DoubleTapped="{Binding Path=MethodIWishToBindTo}" IsDoubleTapEnabled="True"  />
                    </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
```

The problem, of course, is the error message for my binding to `MethodIWishToBindTo`:

> Invalid value for 'DoubleTapped'. Event values must be text

What is the best way for me to get around this ? I could call the method in the code-behind, however the method uses a property in my ViewModel, `"SelectedItemInList"`, which I don't believe can be accessed from the code behind.

Can anyone offer me some advice for this problem ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: To shed some light on this for people who might find this post in their search - the Interactivity assembly is not yet supported by Windows 8 apps (though they are threatening it will be supported in the future!). There are some disassembled 3rd party versions available (a quick Google will find you some results) though they seem, from a quick glance, to be extremely unreliable - though I cannot offer a full review, as I said I only glanced quickly at them. Still working on a solution to this problem and have yet to find anything I would consider a canonical answer. Let me know if you do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `Interactivity` and a custom behavior to trigger the event.  Here's a post that topically covers an example:
[MVVM-Light EventToCommand Behavior for CheckBox Checked/Unchecked in Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647759/mvvm-light-eventtocommand-behavior-for-checkbox-checked-unchecked-in-silverlight)

MVVM-Light definitely makes this easier, but it's possible without as well.

Here's an example of without: http://blog.roboblob.com/2010/01/26/binding-ui-events-from-view-to-commands-in-viewmodel-in-silverlight-4/

Comment: Windows 8 apps do not seem to support the Interactivity assembly, as far as I can see. It won't let me add a reference to the .dll :( Thanks for the response